# How to get rid of multiple if statements in java?

Tags: java, if-statement

Is there a better way to write this constructor which has multiple `if` statements and multiple arguments? I'm a noob to programming so any leads would be helpful.

```java
public Latency(final double full, final double cpuOne, final double cpuTwo, final double cpuThree, final double cpuFour) {
    if (full > 10.0 || (full <= 0.0)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must check the values");
    }
    this.full = full;
    if (cpuOne == 0 && cpuTwo == 0 && cpuThree == 0 && cpuFour == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("not all can be zero");
    } else {
        if (cpuOne == 0.5) {
            this.cpuOne = full;
        } else {
            this.cpuOne = cpuOne;
        }
        if (cpuTwo == 0.5) {
            this.cpuTwo = full;
        } else {
            this.cpuTwo = cpuTwo;
        }
        if (cpuThree == 0.5) {
            this.cpuThree = full;
        } else {
            this.cpuThree = cpuThree;
        }
        if (cpuFour == 0.5) {
            this.cpuFour = full;
        } else {
            this.cpuFour = cpuFour;
        }
    }
}
```

I think this code doesn't need much of context as it is pretty straight forward.

I found out that we can't use `switch` statements for type `double`. How to optimize this?

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of possible ways of refactoring the code that you've written, and there are pros and cons of each one.  Here are some ideas.

**Idea One - use the conditional operator**

You could replace the `else` block with code that looks like this.  This is just effectively a shorter way of writing each of the inner `if/else` blocks.  Many people find this kind of form more readable than a bunch of verbose `if/else` blocks, but it takes some time to get used to it.

```
this.cpuOne = cpuOne == 0.5 ? full : cpuOne;
this.cpuTwo = cpuTwo == 0.5 ? full : cpuTwo;
this.cpuThree = cpuThree == 0.5 ? full : cpuThree;
this.cpuFour = cpuFour == 0.5 ? full : cpuFour;
```

**Idea Two - move common functionality to its own method**

You could have a method something like this

```
private static double changeHalfToFull(double value, double full) {
   if (value == 0.5) {
       return full;
   } else {
       return value;
   }
}
```

then call it within your constructor, something like this.

```
this.cpuOne = changeHalfToFull(cpuOne);
this.cpuTwo = changeHalfToFull(cpuTwo);
this.cpuThree = changeHalfToFull(cpuThree);
this.cpuFour = changeHalfToFull(cpuFour);
```

This has the advantage that the key logic is expressed only once, so it's less error prone than repeating code over and over.

**Idea Three - use arrays**

You could use an array of four elements in the field that stores these values.  You could also use an array for the constructor parameter.  This has a huge advantage - it indicates that the four CPU values are somehow all "the same".  In other words, there's nothing special about `cpuOne` compared to `cpuTwo`, for example.  That kind of messaging within your code has real value to someone trying to understand this.

```
public Latency(final double full, final double[] cpuValues) {

// validation conditions go here ...

    this.cpuValues = new double[4];
    for (int index = 0; index <= 3; index++) {
        if (cpuValues[index] == 0.5) {
             this.cpuValues[index] = full;
        } else {
             this.cpuValues[index] = cpuValues[index];
        }
    }
}
```

**Or a combination**

You could use some combination of all these ideas.  For example, you might have something like this, which combines all three of the above ideas.

```
public Latency(final double full, final double[] cpuValues) {

// validation conditions go here ...

    this.cpuValues = new double[4];
    for (int index = 0; index <= 3; index++) {
        this.cpuValues[index] = changeHalfToFull(cpuValues[index]);
    }
}


private static double changeHalfToFull(double value, double full) {
    return value == 0.5 ? full : value;
}
```

There are obviously other possibilities.  There is no single correct answer to this question.  You need to choose what you're comfortable with, and what makes sense in the larger context of your project.

Comment: A most thorough answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

###### DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself

Each `if` is essentially the same. Put it in a separate method and call the method once for each `cpu*` variable.

```java
public class Latency {
    private double full;
    private double cpuOne;
    private double cpuTwo;
    private double cpuThree;
    private double cpuFour;

    public Latency(final double full,
                   final double cpuOne,
                   final double cpuTwo,
                   final double cpuThree,
                   final double cpuFour) {
        if (full > 10.0 || (full <= 0.0)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must check the values");
        }
        this.full = full;
        if (cpuOne == 0 && cpuTwo == 0 && cpuThree == 0 && cpuFour == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not all can be zero");
        }
        else {
            this.cpuOne = initCpu(cpuOne);
            this.cpuTwo = initCpu(cpuTwo);
            this.cpuThree = initCpu(cpuThree);
            this.cpuFour = initCpu(cpuFour);
        }
    }

    private double initCpu(double cpu) {
        return cpu == 0.5 ? full : cpu;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        new Latency(9.99, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 0.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this one! I have a doubt here. So, in the method we are checking ```if cpu == 0.5``` ? If that is true then we are assigning value of full to cpu right? But we are not assigning value of cpu to cpu itself when it is false. I might be wrong but can you please correct me?

Comment: @anyonymousgamer it is referred to as the [ternary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html). If the method parameter (i.e. `cpu`) equals 0.5 then the method returns `full`, otherwise the method returns `cpu` (i.e. the method parameter). We can do this since we already assigned a value to `full` in the constructor before the calls to method `initCpu`.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you for the teaching. Will look into ternary operator more! Also, one last doubt - I'm trying to return the constructor above in a method (present in separate class) like this - return new Latency(9.99, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 0.5). Is there a better way instead of this? Because it would be odd if the more parameters grow?

Comment: @anyonymousgamer refer to [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs) You should post your _last doubt_ as a new, separate question. And you can show your appreciation by either accepting my answer or up-voting it (or both).